# How to set background url for css files in thymeleaf?

Tags: css, background-image, thymeleaf, relative-path

I have a thymeleaf template where I don't have CSS files imported and wanted to declare style attribute for the body element with `background-image: url{/image.jpg}` property with relative image URL. I wanted to load the URL without including the application context name(`/myapp/`) it. It is similar to the problem over [here](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/background-url-in-a-css-file-td4024757.html), except it din't work for me.

CSS:

```
<style>
body {
    background: url(../img/Background.jpg)
                no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

But the above CSS doesn't work and it accessed the image at

```
http://localhost/img/Background.jpg.
```

So, I had to give the value as `url(/myapp/img/Background.jpg)` for the image to load properly.

I have the `mvc:resources` configuration properly set in `spring-context.xml` for `/img/` request to load properly and it works in other places.

**spring-context.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="img/**" location="/WEB-INF/img/" />
```

So how to load the background url image css value dynamically using thymeleaf's relative url?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, here's how to set dynamic relative paths in background image url property in the css using thymeleaf's inline text value,

```
<style th:inline="text">
    body{
        background: url{[[@{/img/Background.jpg}]]}
                    no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
</style>
```

which loads the image using relative path and we don't have to specific the 'myapp' context name in the url.

Comment: How would i do this for aurl string?

Comment: @Lucky Hi, I know this is an old subject, but did you please add a particular resource handler ? if yes could you please share ? Thank you

Comment: @Sofiane No need for any ResourceHandlers. If you can add this to any Thymeleaf template it should work fine.

Answer (score 7):

```
    <body th:style="'background-image:url(' + @{/images/background.jpg} + '); background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat; background-size: cover;'">
    </body>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case that helped:
change brackets from curly  to round

```
<style th:inline="text">
body{
    background: url([[@{/img/Background.jpg}]])
                no-repeat center center fixed;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is:

```
<body th:style="'background: url(/img/la-paz-city.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;'">
...
</body>
```

that is all

Comment: not work for me. this work for me `th:style="'background:url('+ @{/image/login-background.jpg} +');'"`

Answer (score 0):

When want to get the image from object, you can do like this.

```
<a th:href="@{/}" class="block-20" th:style="'background-image: url('+${item.mediaContents.get(0).url}+');'">
```

If you want to get the image from static path, you can do like this as mentioned by Jorge above.

```
<a th:href="@{/}" class="block-20" th:style="'background-image: url('+@{/images/bg_18.jpg}+');'">
```