# Thymeleaf URL expression in .css file

Tags: css, background-image, thymeleaf, relative-path

I'm using Spring MVC and the Thymeleaf view engine. I have an external ***style.css*** file with the CSS for my page. In the CSS file, I want to refer to a relative image URL.

This is my ***style.css*** file:

```
.background {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('/path/to/image/bg.png');
}
```

The above tries to access an image with the following URL, which doesn't exist:

```
http://localhost/path/to/image/bg.png
```

My real image is at:

```
http://localhost/myapp/path/to/image/bg.png
```

This StackOverflow question gives the answer to my question for inline CSS: [How to set background url for css files in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789526/how-to-set-background-url-for-css-files-in-thymeleaf)

But how do I do this for an external .css file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put all your images folder structure with images `path/to/image/bg.png` inside the `images` folder under `resources/static`. Then refer to it in CSS as:

```
.background {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/path/to/image/bg.png');
}
```

And then you can use this CSS in your templates as:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/css/application.css}"/>
</head>
```

Your files structure should look like this:

[image]

Comment: background-image: url('../images/path/to/image/bg.png');

Comment: @MarufHamidi exactly! Thank you for the corrections.