# Setting of background image through css in thymeleaf not working

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using following css formatting to display a loading  panel on form submission, and I have stored the gif image in \src\main\resources\static , but the the html div is not picking up the image, it takes all the other css formattings except the image. I have referred the following SOF  link, but the mentioned solutions are not working. any one came across similar issue?

[How to set background url for css files in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789526/how-to-set-background-url-for-css-files-in-thymeleaf)

```
<style >

  #loader {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;

                
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75) url([[@{/loading2.gif}]]) no-repeat center center;
  
  z-index: 10000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set `display: none;` - therefore an element, including background image, is invisible. Get rid of this property.

Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Actually the CSS is enabled by jquery when the form is submitted using          ``` var spinner = $('#loader');
          spinner.show(); ``` only problem is with the image, other styles working fine

Comment: When you open dev tools in web browser and check internals of the rendered `#loader` element...  is background url as expected?